# How fast would winds be on a terrestrial planet with a 12 hour day?

Tags: science-based, planets, hard-science, climate, wind

I'm designing a high gravity (1.38g) world with a fast rotation rate (12 hours). I think the circulation cells would be stronger with a faster rotation rate, but I'm trying to figure out what a realistic range of wind speeds would be. If the atmospheric pressure was about the same or a little greater than on Earth, what would winds be like on this planet?

Comment: only the Coriolis force will increase. but that is quite a small force on the surface of the earth. your wind speeds may even drop because the planet is heated more evenly.

Comment: @PostlimFort - that piece about even heating is interesting.  Would you turn this comment into an answer and unpack those ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Winds blow because of differences in air pressure**

Rotation of planet has nothing to do with wind speed. On earth, we observe that sometimes there is no wind or movement of air, tree leaves are halted, sand or dust particles are stand still even though the earth is rotating and gravity is present.

When air is heated at one place, its molecules rarefy, reducing its density. Hot air rises up and cold, dense air flows from sides.

Answer (score 0):

like imtaar said

> When air is heated at one place, its molecules rarefy, reducing its density. Hot air rises up and cold, dense air flows from sides.

If the whole atmosphere is heated evenly then the density reduces evenly. Meaning that there is no or less colder/denser air that can flow in from the side creating the wind we feel. Wind speed is proportional to the difference in density of the air at the same elevation.

The atmosphere is almost exclusively heated by the light coming from the nearest star. So it is heated during the day and is allowed to cool at night. When the day-length is shorter the atmosphere has less time to heat up and cool down. Resulting in a smaller change in temperature between the night air and the day air. This lower difference in temperature means that the density difference is also less. Resulting in less strong winds.

tidally locked planets experience the reverse of this. A planet circling band of hurricanes distribute the scorching heat from the perpetual day side to the frigid perpetual night side.

I do not know exactly at what spin rate the Coriolis force becomes significant. But 12h is for sure still way to slow.

There may be an effect on the difference in temperature at the pole and the equator. Heat distribution may be hindered a little by the Coriolis force in the north south direction. I unfortunately have no idea on how to back this up. or even quantify it. I may or may not cancel out the day/night side difference.